# Operation Not Allowed Active Reactive Context - Subset in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny, subset, reactive

I want to create a subset dataframe in shiny to output various filtered options in my ploy. In the UI, my variable PLAN_DIM_CK are my different choices, and each PLAN_DIM_CK number is the what I want to subset by. When I run the code, I get the error "Operation not allowed without an active reactive context (You tried to do something that can only be done inside a reactive expression or observer.)
Can anyone help me with where this issue lies?

# Filter by plan in UI

```
selectInput(inputId = "PlanID",
              label = "Select a Plan",
              choices = unique(vbc2$PLAN_DIM_CK)
```

In the server

```
#within server 

subsetTest <- reactive ({
    subset(vbc2, PLAN_DIM_CK == input$planID)})

  y <- subsetTest()$RISK_ADJUSTED_HBR
  x <- subsetTest()$PANEL_SIZE


output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data = subsetTest(), aes(x=y,y=x))
```

Answer (score 0):

My best guess would be that you need to use `observe`. The `x` and `y` variables should be inside `observe`, something similar to this:

```
observe({
 y <- subsetTest()$RISK_ADJUSTED_HBR
  x <- subsetTest()$PANEL_SIZE

})
```

Using global variables like this is not a good option. I would suggest you put this `x` and `y` variables inside your `renderPlot` or create `reactive` variables from it.

Putting it inside the `renderPlot` could be something like this:

```
output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
 y <- subsetTest()$RISK_ADJUSTED_HBR
  x <- subsetTest()$PANEL_SIZE
    ggplot(data = subsetTest(), aes(x=y,y=x))
)}
```

Using `reactive` you could do something like this:

```
 subsetTest <- reactive ({
    subset(vbc2, PLAN_DIM_CK == input$planID)})

  y <- reactive({subsetTest()$RISK_ADJUSTED_HBR})
  x <- reactive({subsetTest()$PANEL_SIZE})


output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

    ggplot(data = subsetTest(), aes(x=y(),y=x()))
```

Also, it would be better that you provide a minimal reproducible example from next time so that it would be easy to help you.